# HTML5 tables - I want only certain columns to adjust width when browser is resized

Tags: html, html-table

Title says it all, but here are more details.  I have a table with 8 columns.  2 of these columns contain information that I wouldn't mind truncating if the table is resized, but the other columns contain information that should be shown in full.  So I when the table is resized and made narrower, I would like all the narrowing to occur only in those two columns, not in the others.

Comment: Does setting a specifc width on the columns you don't want to resize not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the cells that you don't want to wrap a class (`.nowrap`), Then add the following CSS:

```
td.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W8MkN/)

Comment: Thanks.  Would be even better for my purposes if the text in the shrinking cells was truncated instead of wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a media query to achieve this. Once the table element gets to a certain width, hide or shrink the columns. Something like this, you will have to tweak it and possibly add more. Also check out Twitter Bootstrap. You can easily achieve this using their framework.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {  
#tableColumn {
display:block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {  
#tableColumn {
display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, I'd prefer not to use any third-party frameworks to achieve this goal.

Comment: @JonCrowell You can use a media query without using Bootstrap. Media Queries are part of CSS3.